# Access is denied when trying to close an exe through C# in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I opening and closing an application through my windows form application but the problem is, I am getting **Access denied** error.

Here is the code snippet from the project.

```
try
{
    //This loop wil check the timing.
    for (int i = 0; i < exeStartTimes.Count; i++)
    {
        if (hour == exeStartTimes[i].hour && minute == exeStartTimes[i].minute)
        {
            if (CheckExeIsOpen(tbExeName.Text) == false)
            {
                Process p = new Process();
                p.StartInfo.FileName = (tbExeLocation.Text + tbExeName.Text);
                p.Start();
                AppendLogFile("Started " + tbExeLocation.Text + tbExeName.Text + " on " + time);
            }
        }

        if (hour == exeEndTimes[i].hour && minute == exeEndTimes[i].minute)
        {
            if (CheckExeIsOpen(tbExeName.Text) == true)
            {
                CloseExe(tbExeName.Text);
                AppendLogFile("Closed " + tbExeName.Text + time);
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Win32Exception w) 
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error occured : " + w.Message);
    AppendLogFile("message      :   " + w.Message);
    AppendLogFile("ErrorCode    :   " + w.ErrorCode.ToString());
    AppendLogFile("Native       :   " +w.NativeErrorCode.ToString());
    AppendLogFile("StackTrace   :   " + w.StackTrace);
    AppendLogFile("Source       :   " + w.Source);
    Exception e = w.GetBaseException();
    AppendLogFile(e.Message);
}
```

And here are the close EXE methods:

```
private bool CheckExeIsOpen(string exeName)
{
    string name = exeName.Split('.')[0];
    foreach (var process in Process.GetProcesses())
    {
        if (process.ProcessName == name)//process name matched return true appliation is open
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;//process name not matched return false appliation is closed  
}

private void CloseExe(string exeName)
{
    string name = exeName.Split('.')[0];
    foreach (var process in Process.GetProcesses())
    {
        if (process.ProcessName == name)
        {
            process.Kill();
            AppendLogFile(tbExeName.Text + " Closed on " + DateTime.Now);
        }
    }
}
```

The error details include

1. message      :   Access is denied
2. ErrorCode    :   -2147467259

I have found that it is creating problem when I am closing the application.

Comment: And what is your CloseExe and CheckExeIsOpen?

Comment: Ok i have added both methods.

Comment: Maybe it's terminating? If the call to the Kill method is made while the process is currently terminating, a Win32Exception is thrown for Access Denied.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.kill?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Diagnostics_Process_Kill

Comment: Strangely fitting username

Comment: The Kill method executes asynchronously. After calling the Kill method, call the WaitForExit method to wait for the process to exit, or check the HasExited property to determine if the process has exited.

Comment: Actually the app is killing but also generating this exception.

Comment: try this: process.Kill(); process.WaitForExit();

Comment: @AccessDenied I guess the problem has resolved, answer it in detail.

Comment: There is a nasty bug in this code, it can easily try to terminate the wrong process.  Process.ProcessName is not good enough to reliably identify the process.  Two completely different programs may have the same name.  Process.Id is the better way to identify the process, albeit not 100% reliable either when you can't be sure if the process still exists.  You do have the proper way already in your code, it is the `p` variable.  Be sure to also use it to Kill() it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.kill?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Diagnostics_Process_Kill):

> The Kill method executes asynchronously. After calling the Kill
>   method, call the WaitForExit method to wait for the process to exit,
>   or check the HasExited property to determine if the process has
>   exited.

and

> If the call to the Kill method is made while the process is currently
>   terminating, a Win32Exception is thrown for Access Denied.

The problem is that you call Kill twice and second call throws exception.
So, the solution would be to call:

```
process.Kill(); 
process.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: This resolved my issue.  I would only add that I intentionally put that code in to an If/Then, checking to see if the Process had already exited, as, in my own case, my design called for a slow loop looking for a Process that could have already exited.